# Does golangs os.Stat open the file?

Tags: go, file-io

Does the `os.Stat(path string) (os.FileInfo, error)` function (try to) open the file which is located at `path`, or is there any trickery involved so that it doesn't need to?

Also, what is the performance penalty for opening/closing files multiple times (no reads/writes, I know these are slow), instead of doing it just once? Is it Hard-Disk bound? Does it differ between OSs?

Comment: When asking questions like this, I'd recommend reading the source code. (it's pretty well-documented and generally easy to read)

Comment: The answer to this question may also vary considerably depending on the platform.

Comment: I am not the most proficient source code crawler, but [what I found](https://golang.org/src/os/stat.go?s=309:349#L1) doesn't help me at all.  Finding the [`statNolog` functions definition](https://golang.org/src/os/stat_unix.go), doesn't help me either, [`syscall.Stats`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_linux_amd64.go?s=3452:3500#L54) is totally cryptic to me, and I cannot find the source for `fillFileStatFromSys`, but I guess it redirects to syscall somewhere, which then again I won't understand.

Comment: it's a syscall to the operation system, like a wrapper, depends on the OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat) doesn't really explain why you'd want a `FileInfo`, or how it's retrieved. I suspect they're assuming that most readers will recognize, from the name, that it's a cross-platform abstraction for the Unix call [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/stat.html), and will already be aware of what that means. This isn't unique to Go—countless other languages' standard libraries have a similarly-named function and similar assumptions in the docs. (See [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat), for example.)

The point of the `stat` function is to get metadata (size, creation time, etc.) about a file without having to open it. There are two reasons this is important:

- You may not have permissions to open the file.
- Reading just the metadata can be a lot more efficient (no need to read the data stream, create an entry in the kernel's open file table, etc.).

And, as you saw in the docs, `os.Stat` is implemented on most platforms as `stat` or [`fstatat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstatat).<sup>1</sup>

So, if you want to get the size of a file, `os.Stat` is a lot faster than, say, opening the file, seeking to the end, and getting the current position. Or even just opening the file and closing it. But it's still not free.

With most Unix filesystems, it works by reading an inode, a single disk block with all the key information about a file, and inode allocation is usually optimized. (It also requires reading at least one directory, since you're specifying the file by name, but that gets cached for the usual case where performance matters, scanning a whole directory or tree.)

And there definitely are platform differences. The biggest,<sup>2</sup> as usual, is between Windows and everybody else. Windows' NTFS filesystem caches most, but not all, of the same information in the directory entries, so if you only want that information, you don't even need to go to the (equivalent to an) inode, and it's much faster. But if you want everything, it's slower. Tools like `find` that are all about searching directory trees have to optimize for these differences, but for most programs, it isn't an issue; just call `stat`. Or, in Go, `os.Stat`.

---

<sub>1. That `fillFileStatFromSys` function you were confused by just reorganizes the information in the struct returned by `stat` into the format Go wants to present, so you don't have to deal with the equivalent of awkward C macros and legacy timestamp formats and so on.</sub>

<sub>2. Historically, there have been platforms where there was nothing remotely like `stat`, and to simulate it, you really did have to open and close the file. But I don't think Go runs on any of those platforms.</sub>